# Comment box emails you

Tags: html, coldfusion, comments

I need to make a comment box that emails you when you submit

the  code for the box but his in my comment but i does not email me

```
<!-- HTML comment box by Liam Gill --> 
<form action="/html/tags/html_form_tag_action.cfm" method="post"> 
     Teacher Comments:<br /> 
     <textarea name="comments" id="comments"> Students comments </textarea><br /> 
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form> 

<p style="font-size:10px;"><a href=liam.htm">Build website</a></p>
```

Comment: <!-- HTML comment box by Liam Gill -->
<form action="/html/tags/html_form_tag_action.cfm" method="post">
  Teacher Comments:<br />
  <textarea name="comments" id="comments">
  Students comments
  </textarea><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<p style="font-size:10px;"><a href=liam.htm">Build website</a></p>

Comment: are you using any server script to handle the form when POST or GET?

Comment: if you want an answer, provide some code to show what you've tried and post the error messages you've received.

Comment: You never told which programming language you speak :)

Comment: @Liam: edit your question to add code rather than posting it as a comment; it's nearly unreadable as an unformatted comment...

Comment: First thing I thought when I saw the title of this question: _"In Soviet Russia..."_

Comment: @LiamYorkville added your comment's code to your post

Comment: What's in `html_form_tag_action.cfm`?

Answer (score 3):

The key is the contents of the cfm file you list as the action. Assuming it has a CFMAIL tag properly formatted in it and the from=, to=, and subject= attributes are defined...

Is an SMTP server defined in the ColdFusion Administrator? If not, is one being defined in the CFMAIL tag?

We're going to need more information in order to help you.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with straight HTML. E-mail messages cannot be sent with just a web page.  You need something server-side.

PHP is a common technology for handling stuff like this.  You can get started by [reading a tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/).  Once you have done that, read up on the [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) command.

The code you posted in your comment references a ColdFusion script, which I am guessing you don't have handy.

Answer (score 0):

READ: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f8e.html

You'll need it in your html_form_tag_action.cfm

Answer (score 0):

You can use ‘mailto:me@mydomain.com’ in the action field of the form. When the user presses the submit button of the form, the browser will first show a warning box that the user’s email address will be revealed to the recipient.

If the user decides to proceed, the form data will be sent to the address mentioned in the mailto: tag. The browser will open the default mail client to send the data by email.

Example:

```
<form action="mailto:you@yourdmainhere.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain" >  
    FirstName:<input type="text" name="FirstName">  
    Email:<input type="text" name="Email">  
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfif isDefined('FORM.comments')>
     <cfmail to="youremail@gmail.com" from="someemail@gmail.com" subject="Student Comments">
          #FORM.comments#
     </cfmail>
     <p>Your Message has been sent!</p>
</cfif>

<form action="path/to/this/page" name="form" method="post"> 
 Teacher Comments:<br /> 
 <textarea name="comments" id="comments"> Students comments </textarea><br /> 
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form> 

<p style="font-size:10px;"><a href=liam.htm">Build website</a></p>
```

Make sure your SMTP server is setup correctly in the Coldfusion Administrator too.